# Rails rake aborted! can't convert Hash into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ok i had this working and i'm not sure what i could have changed to make `rake db:create` not working now. I ran `rake db:drop` to drop my db so i can start from scratch and now `rake db:create` is having a problem.

Here's my stacktrace below. I'm not sure how to go about troubleshooting this.

```
$ rake db:create --trace
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:create
rake aborted!
can't convert Hash into String
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `initialize'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/activerecord-3.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:17:in `new'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/activerecord-3.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:17:in `mysql2_connection'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/activerecord-3.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:304:in `new_connection'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/activerecord-3.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:323:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/activerecord-3.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/activerecord-3.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:261:in `loop'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/activerecord-3.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:261:in `block in checkout'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/activerecord-3.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:260:in `checkout'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/activerecord-3.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:162:in `connection'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/activerecord-3.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:409:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/activerecord-3.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/activerecord-3.1.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:89:in `connection'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/activerecord-3.1.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:86:in `rescue in create_database'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/activerecord-3.1.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:54:in `create_database'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/activerecord-3.1.8/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:227:in `call'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:227:in `block in execute'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:222:in `each'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:222:in `execute'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:166:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/task.rb:152:in `invoke'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:141:in `invoke_task'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `each'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `block in top_level'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `top_level'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:71:in `block in run'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:158:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:68:in `run'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/gems/rake-10.0.2/bin/rake:37:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/TomCaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@famnfo/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create
```

database.yml

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: FamNFo_development

  # local
  username: root
  password: 

  # server
  # username: famnfo_dev
  # password: Panther89!1

  # local
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

  # server
  # socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock 

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: FamNFo_test
  # local
  # username: root
  # password: 

  # server
  username: root
  password: 

  # local
   socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

  # server
  #socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock 

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: FamNFo_production
  # local
  # username: root
  # password: 

  # server
  username: myusername
  password: mypassword

  # local
  # socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

  # server
  socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: What does your config/database.yml look like?

Comment: Wow oddly enough, the space before `socket` in my test section of database.yml was throwing it off. I got rid of that space and it worked just fine.

Comment: That's because YAML was seeing that as a sub-key to your password, thus password was a hash instead of a string. Voila!

Comment: Interesting. Can you post that as an answer and i'll give you the credit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have extra leading spaces before a key in your YAML file it is interpreted as a sub-key, and thus the upper key is interpreted as a hash instead of a string. So removing the extra space before `socket` in the test section should fix the problem.